# Django ORM leaks connections when using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, django, multithreading, postgresql, threadpool

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to speed up data processing. The problem is that the thread pool creates new database connections and Django doesn't close them. I do have CONN_MAX_AGE in `settings.py` and I already tried to call `django.db.close_old_connections()`.

Here is a code example:

```
def compute(job):
    result = FooModel.objects.filter(...).aggregate(...)
    return BarModel.objects.create(result)

def process(dataset):
    thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
    futures = []

    for job in dataset:
        futures += [thread_pool.submit(compute, job)]

    results = list(r.result() for r in wait(futures)[0])
    return results

for i in range(0, 100):
    process(['foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
```

Is Django ORM able to terminate idle DB connections if they were started in another thread?

---

UPD:
Interestingly, Django doesn't even know about these connections:

```
>>> from django.db import connections
>>> print(len(connections.all()))
>>> 2
```

```
mypostgresdb=# select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
   182
(1 row)
```

And all workers threads were already closed for sure:

```
>>> #  workers threads were closed:
>>> import threading
>>> threading.enumerate()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140660203321088)>]
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Dougyfresh I didn't find a solution. The workaround was to create the `ThreadPoolExecutor` only once (e.g. don't create it inside a loop multiple times), so there were no more than 20 extra DB connections.

Comment: Just added a workaround that I created as an answer.

Comment: From [this report](https://bugs.python.org/issue24882), `ThreadPoolExecutor` would not reuse threads. It was fixed in Python 3.8.
I think that may be the cause of connections leak when CONN_MAX_AGE > 0, because the django queries will be ran in new threads, which will cause new connections to be opened.
I currently use Python 3.7.7 and have a similar problem.

Answer (score 14):

My guess is that the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) is not what is creating the DB connection, but the threaded jobs are the ones holding the connection. I've had to deal with this already.

I ended up building this wrapper, to ensure that threads are closed manually whenever jobs are done in a ThreadPoolExecutor. This should be useful in ensuring connections are not leaked, so far I haven't seen any leaking while using this code.

```
from functools import wraps
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from django.db import connection

class DjangoConnectionThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor):
    """
    When a function is passed into the ThreadPoolExecutor via either submit() or map(), 
    this will wrap the function, and make sure that close_django_db_connection() is called 
    inside the thread when it's finished so Django doesn't leak DB connections.

    Since map() calls submit(), only submit() needs to be overwritten.
    """
    def close_django_db_connection(self):
        connection.close()

    def generate_thread_closing_wrapper(self, fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                self.close_django_db_connection()
        return new_func

    def submit(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        I took the args filtering/unpacking logic from 
   
        https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py 
        
        so I can properly get the function object the same way it was done there.
        """
        if len(args) >= 2:
            self, fn, *args = args
            fn = self.generate_thread_closing_wrapper(fn=fn)
        elif not args:
            raise TypeError("descriptor 'submit' of 'ThreadPoolExecutor' object "
                        "needs an argument")
        elif 'fn' in kwargs:
            fn = self.generate_thread_closing_wrapper(fn=kwargs.pop('fn'))
            self, *args = args
    
        return super(self.__class__, self).submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can just use this:

```
    with DjangoConnectionThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, args_list))
```

...and be confident that the connections will close.

Comment: What if I want to reuse connections (when CONN_MAX_AGE > 0)? That behavior is basically the same of when CONN_MAX_AGE = 0, i.e. django closes the connection at request finalization.

Comment: If you open multiple connections you can do `from django.db import connections ; connections.close_all()`. For more information you can check [this blog](https://www.programmersought.com/article/3618244269/)

Comment: Thank you!  This can be simplified with just using try/finally, btw.   try: return fn(...) finally: self.close_django_db_connection()

Comment: @rrauenza you're quite right. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The full document is [here](https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=00001-1ed7200e-c477-41de-a800-10c86fc41dd2)

The final solution is to find an opportunity to actively close the database connection. Specific to our project, every time a worker thread completes a task, it closes its related connection, because we use ThreadPoolExecutor, so Django can easily do this. a little.
The code is as follows:

```
from django.db import connections

def on_done(future):
    connections.close_all()

def main():
     with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        while True:
            future = executor.submit(do, get_a_job())
            future.add_done_callback(on_done)
```

Comment: Is this really working? Because as I understand, the callback is done in the main thread, so the reference to the thread's connection (local to the thread) isn't available anymore.

Comment: @u890106
Yes of course. We used this solution for fixed Django ORM connection leaks.

Comment: From my testing, it does not solve the problem. The main thread does not see the connections opened by the workers threads. They need to be closed from within, like this example https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22420#comment:28

Comment: `future.add_done_callback` doesn't help because it runs in the main thread and not inside the feature.
I tried to print the pointers of the connections in it and it only sees the connections of the main thread. When I print the connections inside the feature, they’re different.
Python 3.8, Django 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

`django.db.close_old_connections()` and `CONN_MAX_AGE` doesn't works when you're in other threads, it only works for the main thread.

Django always open new connections for new threads, and it leaves there to no one. You should make sure to close then before returning to main thread using `db.connections.close_all()`.

```
from django import db

def compute(job):
    result = FooModel.objects.filter(...).aggregate(...)
    bar_model = BarModel.objects.create(result)
    db.connections.close_all()
    return bar_model
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, neither `connection.close()`, nor `connections.close_all()` (both inside the job), nor the `CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS` or `CONN_MAX_AGE` parameters worked.

To solve the problem I had to change the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor`. As they are independent processes, when the OS kills them the connections are closed.

For the record, I'm using Python 3.11, and Django 4.2.2 with psycopg2 2.9.6

Comment: For those who vote negatively, it would be nice if you could comment on why you consider that my answer does not add up. I have listed everything I tried, and what worked for me in my particular case...