# Django: for loop through parallel process and store values and return after it finishes

Tags: django

I have a for loop in django. It will loop through a list and get the corresponding data from database and then do some calculation based on the database value and then append it another list

```
def getArrayList(request):
    list_loop = [...set of values to loop through]

    store_array = [...store values here from for loop]

    for a in list_loop:
         val_db = SomeModel.objects.filter(somefield=a).first()
         result = perform calculation on val_db
         store_array.append(result)
```

The list if 10,000 entries. If the user want this request he is ready to wait and will be informed that it will take time

I have tried `joblib` with `backed=threading` its not saving much time than normal loop

But when i try  with `backend=multiprocessing`. it says "Apps aren't loaded yet"

I read multiprocessing is not possible in `module` based files.

So i am looking at `celery` now. I am not sure how can this be done in celery.

Can any one guide how can we faster the for loop calculation using mutliprocessing techniques available.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [**`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), which is a high level api for processing cpu bound tasks

```
def perform_calculation(item):
    pass

# specify number of workers(default: number of processors on your machine)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
     res = executor.map(perform_calculation, tasks)
```

#### EDIT

In case of `IO` bound operation, you could make use of [**`ThreadPoolExecutor`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) to open a few connections in parallel, you can wrap the pool in a `contextmanager` which handles the cleanup work for you(close idle connections). Here is [**one example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211476/django-orm-leaks-connections-when-using-threadpoolexecutor) but handles the connection closing manually.

Comment: how can I save the calculation in results

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi results are returned as a generator, you can loop through it using normal for loop.

Comment: I would first profile the loop, cause it's much more likely that the database query is the problem and not the computation.

Comment: @Melvyn agree with you, query in a large for loop, not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're very likely looking for the wrong solution. But then again - this is pseudo code so we can't be sure.

In either case, your pseudo code is a self-fulfilling prophecy, since you run queries in a for loop. That means network latency, result set fetching, tying up database resources etc etc. This is never a good pattern, at best it's a last resort.

The simple solution is to get all values in one query:

```py
list_values = [ ... ]
results = []
db_values = SomeModel.objects.filter(field__in=list_values)

for value in db_values:
    results.append(calc(value))
```

If for some reason you need to loop, then to do this in celery, you would mark the function as a task (plenty of examples to find). It won't speed up anything. But you won't speed up anything - it will we be run in the background and so you render a "please wait" message and somehow you need to notify the user again that the job is done.

I'm saying somehow, because there isn't a really good integration package that I'm aware of that ties in all the components. There's [django-notifications-hq](https://pypi.org/project/django-notifications-hq/), but if this is your only background task, it's a lot of extra baggage just for that - so you may want to change the notification part to "we will send you an email when the job is done", cause that's easy to achieve inside your function.

And thirdly, if this is simply creating a report, that doesn't need things like automatic retries on failure, then you can simply opt to use [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html) and a browser-native websocket to start and report on the job (which also allows you to send email).

Comment: Also w.r.t.`SomeModel.objects.filter(field__in=list_values)`. I have to fetch more values from few more models.

So you mean to say `since you run queries in a for loop. ` will not work with multiprocessing

Comment: I'm not saying you can't. You just won't see any difference, because in my experience the computation is not the slowest thing in the loop. Queries will be and they're i/o bound, not CPU bound. But profile it first, in case I'm wrong and your computations last even longer.

Comment: I index my tables and are generally very fast